# using a variable in oledb command

Tags: c#, sql, concatenation, oledb

What is the correct way to concatenate a variable when using the oledb command function in c# for a sql query. To apply some context im trying to make what a list box displays dependent on another selection made on a previous list box.This is what I've tried but doesn't work.

```
OleDbCommand projects = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *  FROM  Client_projects  
WHERE clients = " + (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) , conn);


OleDbDataReader project = projects.ExecuteReader();
while (project.Read())

                {

                    // Add items from the query into the listbox

                    listBox2.Items.Add(project[1].ToString());


                }
```

Comment: The correct way is to pass in a parameter with the value.

Comment: Is clients a varchar? Then use `WHERE clients =' "+ (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "'"`

Comment: @SurajS I tried your code and it still fails what do you mean by a varchar at the moment im using dummy values which are 'Client 1' , 'Client 2' etc

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do you pass in as a paramter do you have any example code

Comment: @JamesPiper What exception do you get? and shouldnt `project[1]` be `project[0]`?

Comment: @JamesPiper and `what do you mean by a varchar at the moment` I meant is the 'clients' column in sql defined as a varchar?

Comment: @SurajS unfortunately due to restraints I have to use an access database and it is project[1] as [0] is the id column

Comment: What exception are you getting??

Comment: @SurajS An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Project V1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can you tell me which line does it show that error @JamesPiper

Comment: @SurajS the c# program crashes and that is the error it displays it is not linked to a particular line

Comment: If you are using visual studio, you should be able to find the line number, since we do not know where the error occurs, a null reference can occur anywhere in the program. Anyway, try this `while(project!=null && project.Read())` Assuming that 'conn' is not null and that is not where the problem is! @JamesPiper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation can lead to SQL Injection problems so you should not use it to build SQL. You should parameterize your query. So something like this...

```
using (OleDbCommand projects = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Client_projects WHERE clients = ?", conn))
{
    projects.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    OleDbDataReader project = projects.ExecuteReader();

    while (project.Read())
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(project[1].ToString());
    }
}
```

OleDbCommand Parameters are set in the order they are specified in the SQL, so if you have more than one you must do them in order.

```
using (OleDbCommand projects = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Client_projects WHERE clients = ? AND Date = ?", conn))
{
    projects.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    projects.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;

    OleDbDataReader project = projects.ExecuteReader();

    while (project.Read())
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(project[1].ToString());
    }
}
```

You are not using it but for other who might, SqlCommand uses named parameters...

```
SELECT * FROM Client_projects WHERE clients = @Clients
projects.Parameters.Add("@Clients", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```